# How to extend ansible aws modules?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, ansible

I'm getting different behavior from the ansible s3 module when I run it as a local library module instead of as a core module.

I want to add the following to the s3.py module https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/stable-1.9/cloud/amazon/s3.py

```
if mode == 'config':
    # Lets check to see if bucket exists to get ground truth.
    bucketrtn = bucket_check(module, s3, bucket)
    if bucketrtn is False:
        create_bucket(module, s3, bucket, location)
    configure_website(s3, bucket, suffix, error_key, redirect_all_requests_to)
```

To test using the ansible s3 module have the following task in my playbook:

```
- s3: "bucket=testsite.com mode=put object=index.html src=index.html"
```

This works without any problem but if I use the same line on my local copy of the s3.py libary named s3_v21.py ie:

```
 - s3_v21: "bucket=testsite.com mode=put object=index.html src=index.html"
```

The result of `bucket_check` is always false.

Answer (score 0):

From debugging further the problem traces back to the Boto library.

The following lines fixes this issue in the boto library https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/2836

```
if '.' in bucket:
    aws_connect_kwargs['calling_format'] = OrdinaryCallingFormat()
```

Problem is that while this calling format is set `s3.lookup("bucketnamewith.period")` returns `none` in my version of the S3 ansible module. But continues to work just fine from the base S3 module. The workaround I have to resort to is to stop using bucket names with periods.